# Remove extensive whitespace with a new line

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently my app saves a workout log like so.

```
Start time: 8:49:41 PM                                                     Objective: 17 pushups a minute for 1 hour                                                                      Total: 1020 pushups                                                     59 minutes have gone by                                                     0 pushups remaining                                                     0 minutes remaining                                                     Times Paused: 0                                                     Finished at: 9:49:41 PM
```

I'm trying to remove the extensive whitespace and new lines by using....

```
string.trim().replace(/[\s]/g," ").toString()
```

The objective is to save the file removing the extensive whitespace with a new line so it's easy to read like so...

```
Start time: 8:49:41 PM
Objective: 17 pushups a minute for 1 hour
Total: 1020 pushups
59 minutes have gone by
0 pushups remaining
0 minutes remaining
Times Paused: 0
Finished at: 9:49:41 PM
```

Thus my question is simple.

How can I remove this extensive whitespace with a new line?

```js
var string = output.textContent.toString();

console.log(string.trim().replace(/[\s]/g," ").toString())
```

```html
<div id="output">
                <h1>
                  Start time: 8:49:41 PM
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  Objective: 17 pushups a minute for 1 hour
                </h1><br>
                
                <h1>
                  Total: 1020 pushups
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  59 minutes have gone by
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  pushups remaining
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  0 minutes remaining
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  Times Paused: 0
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  Finished at: 9:49:41 PM
                </h1>
              </div>
```

Problem solved, Thanks to [Emma's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57815601/710887) wonderful help...

```
string.trim().replace(/\s{2,}/gm,"\n").toString()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, `\s{2,}` might work, or if not, you can try `\s{3,}` or `\s{4,}` being replaced with a new line:

```js
const regex = /\s{2,}/gm;
const str = `Start time: 8:49:41 PM                                                     Objective: 17 pushups a minute for 1 hour                                                                      Total: 1020 pushups                                                     59 minutes have gone by                                                     0 pushups remaining                                                     0 minutes remaining                                                     Times Paused: 0                                                     Finished at: 9:49:41 PM
`;
const subst = `\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iuxWHX/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/iuxWHX/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 1):

Without crazy regular expressions. A split, map, trim, and filter

```js
var string = output.textContent.split(/\n+/).map(s => s.trim()).filter(s => s).join("\n")
console.log(string)
```

```html
<div id="output">
                <h1>
                  Start time: 8:49:41 PM
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  Objective: 17 pushups a minute for 1 hour
                </h1><br>
                
                <h1>
                  Total: 1020 pushups
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  59 minutes have gone by
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  pushups remaining
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  0 minutes remaining
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  Times Paused: 0
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  Finished at: 9:49:41 PM
                </h1>
              </div>
```

A reg exp

```js
var string = output.textContent.trim().replace(/\s*\n\s*/g, '\n').replace(/\n+/,'\n')
console.log(string)
```

```html
<div id="output">
                <h1>
                  Start time: 8:49:41 PM
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  Objective: 17 pushups a minute for 1 hour
                </h1><br>
                
                <h1>
                  Total: 1020 pushups
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  59 minutes have gone by
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  pushups remaining
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  0 minutes remaining
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  Times Paused: 0
                </h1>
                <h1>
                  Finished at: 9:49:41 PM
                </h1>
              </div>
```